# iOS Swift4 how to print short weekday only using DateFormatter()?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I want to have date formatter print only the short weekday label, like "Mon, Tue, Wed".

**What is the correct date format to convert day into 3 letter weekday string?**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "DDD" //prints 278 and like
```

Comment: [Here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Pattern_Examples) is the complete list of date format patterns. It's pretty easy to figure it out. For example `D` is *day of year*

Comment: [Easy Skeezy Date Formatter](http://nsdateformatter.com)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's like I have to learn this stuff every few months all over again:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE"


E..EEE  Tue Abbreviated Day of week name, format style.
EEEE    Tuesday Wide
EEEEE   T   Narrow
EEEEEE  Tu  Short
```

Comment: If this is a stand-alone day of the week, you don't want `EEE`. You want `ccc`. You only use `EEE` if it is in conjunction with a longer string. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns or https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10160/.

Answer (score 5):

Use this http://nsdateformatter.com

```
Monday, Oct 8, 2018 = EEEE, MMM d, yyyy

10/08/2018 = MM/dd/yyyy

10-08-2018 04:29 = MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm

Oct 8, 4:29 AM = MMM d, h:mm a

October 2018 = MMMM yyyy

Oct 8, 2018 = MMM d, yyyy

Mon, 8 Oct 2018 04:29:53 +0000 = E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z

2018-10-08T04:29:53+0000 = yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

08.10.18 = dd.MM.yy
```

Answer (score 3):

A very common use case is to retrieve the weekday from a **Date**.

```swift
let weekdayIndex = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 1
let weekday = DateFormatter().shortWeekdaySymbols[weekdayIndex]
print(weekday)

// Outputs: Fri, Tue or whatever day is today
```

That `-1` on the first line comes from the fact that `Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())` returns a range from 1 to 7, while `shortWeekdaySymbols` expects an index ranging from 0 to 6.

Mind that if you want to obtain other formats such as `Friday` instead of `Fri`, you can use other methods listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293235-weekdaysymbols).